# How to make accessible a automatically created dictionary inside of textDidChange(_:) as data for the NSTableView functions?

Tags: swift, cocoa

I had the suggestion to use function textDidChange() to perform code inside this function automatically. It is working. It is in my Controller class.

Now I am going to use this approach for creating automatically, inside of textDidChange(), a dictionary variable from text, when user is typing in NSTextView. Then, I need this dictionary for the NSTableView functions, to display a Table in application corresponding to the text typed by user. 
**Question is how to make accessible this dictionary from textDidChange(_:) function for the NSTableView functions like**

> numberOfRowsInTableView(tableView: NSTableView)

and

> tableView(tableView: NSTableView, viewForTableColumn tableColumn:
>   NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?

All in the same Controller class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if same dictionary will be your datasource for the tabelview .But for this method you can simply call reloaddata function of tableview to after updating your tableview datasource .

Comment: I am using NSWindowController, and I have tried to add to windowDidLoad() the self.tableView.reloadData(), but I cant, I have the following complain  -  Value of type '(NSTableView, viewForTableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> NSView?' has no member 'reloadData'

Comment: Why I cant call self.tableView.reloadData(),  in Controller class (subclass of NSTableViewDataSource, NSTableViewDelegate), what is a mistake ?

Comment: No idea why you are unable to call it as you can see from docs you method is there https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/reloadData

Comment: Thanks for the tip with self.tableView.reloadData() ! I have played around with datasource, but important thing was to put tableView.reloadData() in textDidChange(), not in windowDidLoad().